# F# Pinvoke error

Tags: .net, winapi, f#, pinvoke, extern

I posted this a few days ago but the answers I got don't seem to be working, so I'm posting it again with some more detail.

I have a project written in F# and I have to use an unmanaged DLL for part of it. In the unmanaged DLL's documentation they provide samples of how to call the functions from C#, like this:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

[DllImport("foo.dll")] public static extern Int32 foo_init(
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.AnsiBStr), In()] ref string FOOarg_Handle,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.AnsiBStr), In()] ref string FOOarg_User, 
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.AnsiBStr), Out()] out string FOOarg_DataOut, 
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.AnsiBStr), Out()] out string FOOarg_ErrOut);
```

I've attempted to translate this into F#, and tried the following:

```
open System
open System.Runtime.InteropServices

[<DllImport(@"foo.dll", EntryPoint="foo_init")>]
extern int fooInit([<MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.AnsiBStr)>]string handle,
                   [<MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.AnsiBStr)>]string user,
                   [<MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.AnsiBStr)>]string result,
                   [<MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.AnsiBStr)>]string error)
```

Then later on I'm trying to call the function:

```
let res = fooInit("", "", "", "")
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work. It compiles but when I run it I end up with an `Unhandled Exception: System.AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.` error.

Does anyone have an idea of how to fix this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to pass pointers to the strings. That's what the `ref` and `out` imply.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, this seems to be working:

```
open System
open System.Runtime.InteropServices

[<DllImport(@"foo.dll", EntryPoint="foo_init")>]
extern int fooInit([<MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.AnsiBStr)>]string& handle,
                   [<MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.AnsiBStr)>]string& user,
                   [<MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.AnsiBStr)>]string& result,
                   [<MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.AnsiBStr)>]string& error)
```

And then I have to call the function this way:

```
let mutable h, u, r, e = "", "", "", ""

let res = fooInit(&h, &u, &r, &e)
```

This article helped me in figuring it out: http://pblasucci.wordpress.com/2012/07/23/managing-pointers-or-fs-platform-invoke-gotcha/

Answer (score 0):

You need to replicate the `[In]` and `[Out]` values as well as the `MarshalAs` ones.

Comment: That didn't work unfortunately. I tried adding `[<In>]` and `[<Out>]` decorators like this: `[<MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.AnsiBStr)>][<In>]string handle`. Got the same exception.